# Bgcolor change of div with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I  am trying to make a webpage so that when a link is clicked, it doesn't go to a page, it changes the background color of a sentence in a div, and also changes the sentence. So far it goes to the page, which is fake.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
Sentence 1
</div>
<div id="div2">
<a href="answer.html" id="c_link" onmousedown="mousedown()">Click to change bgcolor!</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdemo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript- jsdemo.js:

```
function mousedown()
{
document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor="#CCCCCC";
document.div1.innerHTML = "Sentence 2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence doesn't seem to find the div, do this:

```
function mousedown() {
    var container = document.getElementById('div1');
    container.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
    container.innerHTML = "Sentence 2";
}
```

And change the link to

```
<div id="div2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="c_link" onmousedown="mousedown()">Click to change bgcolor!</a>
</div>
```

I saw the other response, and I found that this answer is still valid under two assumptions:

- You won't need to apply other event handlers to this element and event;
- You need compatibility with old browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that inline event handler, and use

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
document.getElementById('c_link').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Avoid following the link
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
    div1.innerHTML = "Sentence 2";
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwa43Lto/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and also, why does your `<a>` tag have a `href` leading to another page?

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)"/>
<div>Sample text</div>

<script>
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  a.onclick = function() {
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to change onmousedown event to onclick event.

```
var link = document.getElementById('c_link');

link.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
    div1.innerHTML = "Sentence 2";

}
```